# Reaction between phenylamine and halogens

Tags: organic-chemistry, aromatic-compounds, halogenation, electrophilic-substitution

I understand that phenylamine is considerably more reactive than benzene, meaning that it is able to react with bromine water to give 2,3,6-tribromophenylamine. But I was then wondering why I haven't seen anywhere mention reactions with other halogens. So will phenylamine react with other halogens to produce a similar compound, I see no reason why it wouldn't happen? Do text books just use bromine water as it is convenient?

Will  $\ce{C_6H_5NH_2 + 3Cl_2 -> C_6H_2NH_2 Cl_3 + 3HCl}$ happen?

Comment: Why would you get N,N-Dichloroaniline instead? and would iodine do the same? Why isn't bromine behaving in this way?

Comment: @user55119 Yeah, redox would happen, but this product is unlikely.

Comment: It's aniline's ring that is easily oxidated, not nitrogen.

Answer (score 2):

Chlorination of aniline with chlorine is rapid and gives 2,4,6-trichloroaniline according to the references cited in this paper [here](https://www.tandfonline.com/doi/pdf/10.1080/00397910802499542). The earliest reference cited is 1845 by AW Hofmann so it has been around a long time. More modern approaches use N-Chlorosuccinimide as the reaction is more controllable

Comment: Why is this the case then?

Comment: In general researchers don't want trichloroaniline, with NCS it is easier to isolate the desired mono or di-chloro aniline products.

Comment: No, why does the reaction of chlorine result in a different product and no chloro aniline?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand you. The reaction of chlorine directly with aniline gives chlorination of the benzene ring with the same substitution pattern as Bromine does.

Comment: Ok, I see now, I didn't read it carefully enough. would iodine behave in the same way then if both chlorine and bromine behave the same?

Comment: As far as I can see iodine is not reactive enough to tri-iodinate. It appears to only go in once to give 4-iodoaniline.

Comment: Do we only get mono-sub due to the deactivating nature of the iodine, thus making it harder to get a di-iodo product?

Comment: It could be that, though iodine is a fairly weak deactivator. Sterics are against it too